# How to get repository permissions on Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I was looking for the solution, but seems that azure api doesn't have this functionality.

I tried to press F12 and to see how it is solver on azure itself, and have found

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{}/_api/_security/DisplayPermissions?__v=5&tfid={fid}&permissionSetId={permissionSetId}&permissionSetToken={permissiontoken}"`.

Where can I find this parameters? Is it the best way to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, is there any updates for this issue? Please feel free to let me know whether my answer helps.

Comment: sorry, I have checked, seems that there is not this functionality on dev.azure now, but on organization server there is
as I have understood in the past it was on azure also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I find this parameters?

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{}/_api/_security/DisplayPermissions?__v=5&tfid={fid}&permissionSetId={permissionSetId}&permissionSetToken={permissiontoken}"
```

For `{}`, where is the project ID, you can use the project name instead of it.

For `tfid` and `permissionSetToken`, the Azure DevOps API is encapsulated in a [PowerShell module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzurePipelinesPS/3.1.27) and has commands for secure namespaces.

For `permissionSetId`, this parameter does not change here and you can replace it with what you have captured in F12

Comment: thank you, about `permissionSetId`: the only way to retrieve is from `F12`?

Comment: what is tfid parameter?